# Split a String in R, using specifc criteria

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have this vector of characters and I need to split the elements in every row.

Here's the image and the code of the dataset:

```
Y = c("Voci dell’attivo 31-dic-2018 31-dic-2017", "10. Cassa e disponibilità liquide 113.154.047 105.800.459", 
"20. Attività finanziarie valutate al fair value con impatto a conto economico 18.400.808 16.926.126", 
"a) attività finanziarie detenute per la negoziazione 4.343.408 4.356.151", 
"c) altre attività finanziarie obbligatoriamente valutate al fair value 14.057.400 12.569.975", 
"30. Attività finanziarie valutate al fair value con impatto sulla redditività complessiva 636.155.429 738.384.151", 
"40. Attività finanziarie valutate al costo ammortizzato 11.203.834.137 11.113.118.111", 
"a) crediti verso banche 3.198.599.841 3.375.218.889", "b) crediti verso clientela 8.005.234.296 7.737.899.222", 
"50. Derivati di copertura 516.238 696.134", "70. Partecipazioni 183.546.796 156.038.259", 
"80. Attività materiali 224.588.110 237.315.814", "90. Attività immateriali 1.917.192 2.041.953", 
"di cui:", "- avviamento 1.650.000 1.650.000", "100. Attività fiscali 222.227.750 175.106.461", 
"a) correnti 4.897.477 10.066.708", "b) anticipate 217.330.273 165.039.753", 
"120. Altre attività 82.551.535 110.120.187", "Totale dell'attivo 12.686.892.042 12.655.547.655", 
"(unità di euro)", "Voci del passivo e del patrimonio netto", 
"31-dic-2018 31-dic-2017", "10. Passività finanziarie valutate al costo ammortizzato 11.375.985.022 11.176.338.096", 
"a) debiti verso banche 146.551.210 144.854.107", "b) debiti verso clientela 10.861.850.231 10.251.703.644", 
"c) titoli in circolazione 367.583.581 779.780.345", "20. Passività finanziarie di negoziazione 2.392.620 2.370.319", 
"40. Derivati di copertura 6.189.059 2.971.997", "60. Passività fiscali 4.091.701 3.909.554", 
"a) correnti 752.147 -", "b) differite 3.339.554 3.909.554", 
"80. Altre passività 239.940.794 152.157.192", "90. Trattamento di fine rapporto del personale 54.720.108 56.331.622", 
"100. Fondi per rischi e oneri: 66.580.390 69.699.078", "a) impegni e garanzie rilasciate 12.705.663 9.475.181", 
"c) altri fondi per rischi e oneri 53.874.727 60.223.897", "110. Riserve da valutazione 119.988.702 139.381.644", 
"140. Riserve 460.527.397 761.938.256", "150. Sovrapprezzi di emissione 126.318.353 126.318.353", 
"160. Capitale 155.247.762 155.247.762", "180. Utile (perdita) d’esercizio (+/-) 74.910.134 8.883.782", 
"Totale del passivo e del patrimonio netto 12.686.892.042 12.655.547.655")
```

Basically what should I do is:

- Put the first numbers/parenthsesis and ALL the following words into a column
- Put the first number in a second column
- Delete the last number

[image]

I don't know how to make R recognize different type of element inside the same string. How can I do this?

Comment: Not clear how you want the expected output as there are cases like `"di cui:"` or `"- avviamento 1.650.000 1.650.000"` or `"a) correnti 752.147 -"`

Comment: in that case "di cui" is a word and has no numbers after so it will occupy the ith row in the first column, but in the second column of the ith line there's nothing so it will remain empty. Simplifying: all the stuff(words, parenthesis and so on..) on the left of the first number must be in the firts column

Comment: looks like there will be a lot of questions if i proceed with this.  I am out

Comment: with package *unglue* you can do `unglue_data(Y,"{text} {number=[0-9.]+} {=.*}")`, into `text` we extract anything, then number should contain numbers or dots after a space, then we have another space followed by anything, which we don't want to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `Y`, this should achieve what you want, or get very close to that:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tibble(orig = str_remove(string = Y, pattern = " [[:digit:][:punct:]]+$")) %>% 
  transmute(col1 = str_remove(string = orig, pattern = " [[:digit:][:punct:]]+$"), 
            col2 = str_extract(string = orig, pattern = "[[:digit:][:punct:]]+$"))
#> # A tibble: 43 x 2
#>    col1                                                        col2        
#>    <chr>                                                       <chr>       
#>  1 Voci dell’attivo 31-dic-2018 31-dic-2017                    -2017       
#>  2 10. Cassa e disponibilità liquide                           113.154.047 
#>  3 20. Attività finanziarie valutate al fair value con impatt… 18.400.808  
#>  4 a) attività finanziarie detenute per la negoziazione        4.343.408   
#>  5 c) altre attività finanziarie obbligatoriamente valutate a… 14.057.400  
#>  6 30. Attività finanziarie valutate al fair value con impatt… 636.155.429 
#>  7 40. Attività finanziarie valutate al costo ammortizzato     11.203.834.…
#>  8 a) crediti verso banche                                     3.198.599.8…
#>  9 b) crediti verso clientela                                  8.005.234.2…
#> 10 50. Derivati di copertura                                   516.238     
#> # … with 33 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

To clarify: using the dollar sign it tells regex to start looking from matches from the end of the string, so what happens with that code is that first it removes the last combination of digits and points, then, from the remaining strings, it either keeps or remove digits and points to create the two columns.